# Leaflet map not aligning GeoServer TMS and not showing most layers

Tags: geoserver, leaflet

I uploaded a GeoTIFF in my store in GeoServer and when I tried to view it via TMS it simply did not show up. So I decided to try it out with some of the sample datasets and some of them showed up. But I realized the coordinates were way off.

image 1
[image: leaflet output]

image 2
[image: geoserver output]

leaflet.html

```
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha512-hoalWLoI8r4UszCkZ5kL8vayOGVae1oxXe/2A4AO6J9+580uKHDO3JdHb7NzwwzK5xr/Fs0W40kiNHxM9vyTtQ=="
        crossorigin="" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512-BB3hKbKWOc9Ez/TAwyWxNXeoV9c1v6FIeYiBieIWkpLjauysF18NzgR1MBNBXf8/KABdlkX68nAhlwcDFLGPCQ=="
        crossorigin=""></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="map" style="height: 700px;"></div>
    <script>
        var map = L.map('map').setView([38.136, -98.686], 3);

        // // http: //localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=wms&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities
        // var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=wms&version=1.3.0', {
        //     layers: 'North America sample imagery'
        // }).addTo(map);
        L.tileLayer(
            'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/nurc%3AImg_Sample@EPSG%3A4326@png/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png', {
                crs:L.CRS.EPSG4326,
                tms: true,
                attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © ',
                maxZoom: 21,
                tileSize: 256,
                zoomOffset: 0,
            }).addTo(map);

        var circle = L.circle([38.136, -98.686], {
            color: 'red',
            fillColor: '#f03',
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
            radius: 500000
        }).addTo(map)
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Image 1 is what is seen via my leaflet.html, image 2 is what I get when I view the tiles normally in the GeoServer. The coordinates seen in image 2 are of me pointing to the middle of the image and they match up with Google Maps so I know they are correct. Image 2 I set the initial viewpoint to these exact coordinates and also the circle to the same coordinates but as you can see it is way off. I think this might be the reason by some of my smaller tile layers are not visible, I might be just looking somewhere else. I also tried WMS but it simply did not work.

[image: tms file]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Error messages and code should be posted as text, not as a screenshot. It is very difficult to read for some users and impossible for screen readers, and google. Please take the [tour] to see how this site works.

Comment: Default CRS for Leaflet maps is `L.CRS.EPSG3857`. Since your TMS layer uses `L.CRS.EPSG4326` and Leaflet support only one CRS per map, you have to set map to use the same CRS with the `crs` option: `crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326`.

Comment: @TomazicM i believe I have done that if look at my leaflet.html under L.tilelayer. perhaps it is not correct?

Comment: @jagrat - you are declaring the EPSG:4326 on the layerlevel - you need to either change your map CRS to EPSG:4326 or you make your layer available in EPSG:3857 via GeoServer - the second would be the prefered way, as EPSG:3857 is the most user-friendly for the Web (Web-Mercator)

Comment: It has to be also `var map = L.map('map', {crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326});`

Answer (score 0):

Default CRS for Leaflet maps is L.CRS.EPSG3857. Since your TMS layer uses L.CRS.EPSG4326 and Leaflet support only one CRS per map, you have to set map to use the same CRS with the crs option: crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326. –
TomazicM

you are declaring the EPSG:4326 on the layerlevel - you need to either change your map CRS to EPSG:4326 or you make your layer available in EPSG:3857 via GeoServer - the second would be the prefered way, as EPSG:3857 is the most user-friendly for the Web (Web-Mercator) –
bloigge

It has to be also var map = L.map('map', {crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326}); –
TomazicM